# Scala to connect Oracle database and perform operation on the query string in spark session

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to oracle database through scala code mentioned below. I want to the perform the operation on query string in spark session. I am not aware the approach for solving the problem.i want to connect to oracle database and fetch the select query result from table and then store the result in Dataframe for further processing.

```
val driver ="jdbc driver name"
val url= "jdbc url"
val username"user1"
val password="pass1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val dataFrame=spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url","pass connection string here")
        .option("driver","pass driver class name")
        .option("user","pass user name")
        .option("password","password goes here")
        //we can use dbtable or query option to pass custom queries
        .option("dbtable","(sql query)dummyname")
        or
       // .option("query","sql query")
        .load()
```